# Structr startup issues

Tags: java, neo4j, structr

I've got the right java version installed and the package unpacked, and I'm getting some errors:

```
WARNING: Error loading module structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar:java.io.FileNotFoundException: structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar             (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Except....this is the SNAPSHOT file in the directory - it looks like the expected version wasn't changed:

structr-ui-2.0-SNAPSHOT-201602031507.0599a.jar

```
SEVERE: Unable to initialize resource provider for servlet JsonRestServlet, no resource provider found. Please check structr.conf for a valid resource provider class.
```

and it finally dies with this message:

```
SEVERE: Vital service HttpService failed to start: No resource provider available for servlet JsonRestServlet. Aborting
```

For the environment, this is what I've got:

```
D:\> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-1110T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: D:\Applications\Apache\Maven\3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

I'm not a java guy so I'm not sure how to interpret this - am I citing the wrong package here? Should I be pathing to something else?

Here's the entire startup log - my guess the failure to open the SNAPSHOT jar file is the cause of the problem.

---

```
D:\Graph\Structr\app>java -cp lib/*;structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar org.structr.Server
Feb 17, 2016 4:53:37 PM org.structr.core.Services initialize
INFO: Reading structr.conf..

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:38 PM org.structr.core.Services getResources
INFO: Found 0 possible resources: []

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:39 PM org.structr.module.JarConfigurationProvider scanResource
WARNING: Error loading module structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar: java.io.FileNotFoundException: structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
        at org.structr.module.JarConfigurationProvider.loadResource(JarConfigurationProvider.java:1095)
        at org.structr.module.JarConfigurationProvider.scanResource(JarConfigurationProvider.java:1013)
        at org.structr.module.JarConfigurationProvider.scanResources(JarConfigurationProvider.java:1002)
        at org.structr.module.JarConfigurationProvider.initialize(JarConfigurationProvider.java:119)
        at org.structr.core.Services.getConfigurationProvider(Services.java:496)
        at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:312)
        at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:296)
        at org.structr.core.Services.getInstance(Services.java:144)
        at org.structr.Server.main(Server.java:36)

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:39 PM org.structr.module.JarConfigurationProvider scanResources
INFO: 5 JARs scanned

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:39 PM org.structr.core.Services initialize
INFO: Starting services

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:39 PM org.structr.neo4j.Neo4jDatabaseService initialize
INFO: Relationship cache size set to 10,000

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:39 PM org.structr.neo4j.Neo4jDatabaseService initialize
INFO: Node cache size set to 10,000

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:39 PM org.structr.neo4j.Neo4jDatabaseService initialize
INFO: Initializing database (./db) ...
SLF4J: This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4j_version

Feb 17, 2016 4:53:55 PM org.structr.core.graph.NodeService initialize
INFO: Database ready.

Feb 17, 2016 4:57:08 PM org.structr.agent.AgentService run
INFO: AgentService started

Feb 17, 2016 4:57:08 PM org.structr.cron.CronService initialize
WARNING: No cron expression for task , ignoring.

Feb 17, 2016 4:57:08 PM org.structr.rest.service.HttpService initialize
INFO: Running in asynchronous mode
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Graph/Structr/app/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Graph/Structr/app/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Feb 17, 2016 4:57:08 PM org.structr.rest.service.StructrHttpServiceConfig initializeFromProperties
SEVERE: Unable to initialize resource provider for servlet JsonRestServlet, no resource provider found. Please check structr.conf for a valid resource provider class.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No resource provider available for servlet JsonRestServlet
        at org.structr.rest.service.StructrHttpServiceConfig.initializeFromProperties(StructrHttpServiceConfig.java:97)
        at org.structr.rest.service.HttpService.collectServlets(HttpService.java:608)
        at org.structr.rest.service.HttpService.initialize(HttpService.java:400)
        at org.structr.core.Services.createService(Services.java:549)
        at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:324)
        at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:296)
        at org.structr.core.Services.getInstance(Services.java:144)
        at org.structr.Server.main(Server.java:36)

Feb 17, 2016 4:57:08 PM org.structr.core.Services createService
SEVERE: Vital service HttpService failed to start: No resource provider available for servlet JsonRestServlet. Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried again, and the only way I got this to work was to remove all the jre* packages from my windows 7 system. The java control panel doesn't seem to work as expected, and structr doesn't run when a jre is driving this particular bus.